# How does MetaMask secure / store unlocked accounts?

Tags: metamask, security, private-key

I understand that MetaMask stores the encrypted vault somewhere like

> C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local
> Extension Settings\nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn

However, when a user entered the password into metamask this vault should be decrypted so the user is able to sign transactions with it. How does MetaMask store and secure this decrypted vault / key when being unlocked?